# How to access a UIATableCell within the app window using UIAutomation in Instruments?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, functional-testing, ios-ui-automation

I have this app for which I am writing automated test scripts using the UIAutomation framework that apple has provided. In my app I want to tap a button which is the child of a `UIATableCell()` which in turn is a child of the `mainWindow()` of my app. When I run the command `logElementTree()` the following is shown:
[image]

I can't access this button however I try. Can anyone please help me how to access this button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    var buttonToTap = mainWindow().cells()[0].buttons()[0].tap();
    if ( buttonToTap.checkIsValid() )
        buttonToTap.tap();
```

If text in the cell you are trying to tap will be not changed during the application run you can try to use the object name instead of the index:

```
var textInCell = "You have not talked to anyone named 'Bugles'";    
var buttonToTap = mainWindow().cells()[textInCell].buttons()[textInCell].tap();
if ( buttonToTap.checkIsValid() )
    buttonToTap.tap();
```

Comment: If I use `mainWindow().cells() `, it gives invalid element error. UIAutomation doesn't seem to recognize that the cell is a direct child  of the window. However I have used `mainWindow().elements()[textInCell].buttons()[textInCell].tap() ` which seems to work. Still it is odd and and I was wondering why UIAutomation would not recognize this? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Based on the logElementTree screenshot you posted above - 'cell' should be there. Try to find out what type of element is it. It could be UIAutomation issue. ...logMessage( mainWindow().elements()[textInCell].toString() ); It should log something like [object UIA<objectType>]